# ASP.NET MVC RouteUrl with dynamic action

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-4

I try to use URLHelp.RouteUrl with dynamic string in javascript.  I want it in this way -

```
function MyFun(action, param){
   var strPass = "MyController/" + action + "?param1=" + param;
   Windows.Location.href = "<%=Url.RouteUrl(" + strPass + ")%>";
}
```

It does not work.  Have I missed anything?  Do we have alternative way in ASP.NET MVC to work in a similar way?

Thanks,

Additional info -

I try the above way because I have a problem from my application - the main page has `"http://myserver/myapplicaiton/mycontroller/myaction"` correctly return when I use `"Windows.Location.href ="MyController/MyAction"`.  But the next page having double controller appeared `"http://myserver/myapplication/mycontroller/mycontroller/myaction"`.
What causes this routing problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a function to get the entire url -

function FullURL(){

```
var app = "<%=HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath.ToString()%>";

if (app == "/")
    app = "";

return location.protocol+'//'+location.hostname+(location.port ? ':'+location.port: '') + app;
```

}

And then call it from -

```
 function MyFun(action, param){          
       Windows.Location =FullURL() + "/MyController/" + action + "?param1=" + param;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This can't work. Razor syntax render's before the html page reaches the browser. Javascript executes after.

So, you are trying to populate step 1 with step 2.

```
   function MyFun(action, param){          
       Windows.Location ="/MyController/" + action + "?param1=" + param;
    }
```

Comment: @Don, I looked at your example, and you are using "Windows.Location.href ="MyController/MyAction". That is not the same as "Windows.Location ="/MyController/MyAction" note that adding a leading **'/'** and removing **'href'** should lead the MVC framework to use the web site root

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  That did not solve my problem.  It returns "http://myserver/mycontroller/myaction" without "/myapplicaiton" after deployed to a server.  It works in Visual Studio 2010 but not after deployed.

Comment: @Don, are you using any special routes? if so, please include them in your answer. Otherwise, I recommend using a redirect action method to which you will pass the action and controller

Answer (score 2):

Try this code instead

```
   function MyFun(action, param){          
       Windows.Location.href ="/MyController/" + action + "?param1=" + param;
    }
```

Comment: That is what I am using.  But this way can not correctly resolve my web site root.  I want a way similar to URL.Content("~/") to get a correct path.

Comment: try using "~/MyController/" + action + "?param1=" + param

Comment: @Don, I admire your urge to follow Best Practice, but you can't dynamically use Url.Content. All Razor syntax is pre-rendered before JS can launch. But, even though it's not best practice, don't fear using simple string path. Dynamic behavior like this requires bending convention a little.

Comment: @Don, I think IC, you need a way to resolve relative root. Is the MVC routing engine falling short for you?

Comment: @Dave A, You are right.  I don't know how to make the routing work.  I added information to my question.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot dynamically add razor code to a view once the code leaves the server... Razor is not compiled on the client browser.

You might use jQuery and make an $.ajax() call up to a Controller/Action which has the sole purpose of returning you a url:

```
public ActionResult GenerateUrlFromRoutingEngine(string ControllerName, string ActionName, string RouteValues) 
{
    var ctx = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
    UrlHelper helper = new UrlHelper(
                           new RequestContext(ctx,
                           RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(ctx));
    var returnUrl = helper.Action(ControllerName,ActionName, RouteValues); //TODO: transform RouteValues to RouteValuesDictionary
    return Content(returnUrl);
}
```

In the $.ajax callback, set  Windows.Location.href = response; (put this javascript on a razor .cshtml file or find a way to pass in the URL intuitively.)

```
function MyFun(action, param){
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: "@{Html.RouteLink("GenerateUrlFromRoutingEngine", "MyController")}",
            data: { ControllerName: 'MyController', ActionName: action, RouteValues: param },
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(response) { Windows.Location.href = response; }
            }
}
```

Comment: using Ajax is definitely a good idea.  I am rushing to finish using regular javascript.  I will try your way later.  Thanks